# Linux vs. Windows copy performance

Tags: rsync, scp

I am attempting to copy files from an old NAS to a new one (I say "new", but the new one is about 8 years old, and the old one is about 12 years old). Since both have RAIDed disks, physically removing them isn't an option. The old NAS is running some sort of embedded Busybox Linux supplied by EMC. The newer one has just been rebuilt, and is running a recent version of Debian. Total amount to be copied is around 8TB. In addition, the only external connections on the old NAS other than network are USB 2.0 connectors, and I'm not even sure they are supported by the operating system, so copying to an external disk and then moving to the new NAS likewise isn't an option.

At any rate, using `rsync` or `rcp` gets me a copy speed of about 20MB/sec. With `scp` I get under 10MB/sec. I also tried piping the output of `tar` from one host to another using `ssh`, and performance was abysmal. However, when I mount both shares on a Windows box and copy the files from one share to another, I am able to achieve around 60MB/sec. All speeds are being determined using iotop and/or iostat; I'm not basing this on Windows speed.

Why is the Linux to Linux copy so slow, and is there anything I can do to increase the speed to what I get with Windows?

ETA: here is the output from `ip a` (interface 3 is disconnected):

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:6f:3f:17:0f:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.227/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp3s0
       valid_lft 57093sec preferred_lft 57093sec
3: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:6f:3f:17:0f:ca brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

ETA2: Output from `ethtool` looks fine to me:

```
# ethtool enp3s0
Settings for enp3s0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: off (auto)
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

Comment: Hello. I don't understand exactly where you need to copy files from. Which communication protocol do you use to copying (FTP, CIFS, NFS, ... Samba or what ?). You also don't mention that you have the correct drivers for your Linux network card installed. How do you test the copy (transfer) speed? What file system do you have on your local Linux disk? Do you use any Linux antivirus system? Your Linux system may have incorrect NIC drivers, a badly configured NIC, a badly configured firewall, or something similar. Try checking your NIC configuration with the `ifconfig` tool as the first step.

Comment: For a *local* copy, ssh makes no sense (crypto overhead). rsync has neen carefully tuned for speed... but it has to compare source/destination.

Comment: @s3n0 I don't know how to check with `ifconfig` (actually `ip a`, since `ifconfig` is deprecated) to see if the drivers are correct, but wouldn't that affect the copy speed when using Windows as well? I don't care which protocol I use, whatever is fastest. When using the Windows box it's SMB, but otherwise it would be whatever I choose. I believe the filesystem on the old NAS is ext3; the new one is ext4 (but again, wouldn't that also affect the Windows copy speed?). Your other questions were answered in my OP (e.g. **from** an old NAS **to** a new one); I'm not sure what you don't understand

Comment: @vonbrand I'm aware of the overhead from `ssh`; that was just a test. Both `rcp` and `rsync` (the latter after a download of a file list from the source server) should run at full speed, no?

Comment: scp goes through ssh, so traffic is encrypted which for many CPU's is a bottleneck.  How do you mount the drive under Linux?

Comment: `ifconfig` was a typo. Sorry for that. I meant to find out if your NIC is detected at the right speed. You can use, for example, the `ethtool eth0` command to determine the NIC speed. Is your NIC connected to only 10Mbit/s ? Maybe your NIC cannot detect the correct speed and will switch to 10Mbit/s mode (just guess the possible causes of your problem).

Comment: @s3n0 I posted the output from `ethtool` in my OP; it looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of scp, have you tried mounting the SMB share of the new NAS onto the old one, then rsync copy the data to the mount point?

Comment: Ugh............

Answer (score 2):

on a 1gbps wired network, *theoretical* max speed is = 1000 mbps / 8 bits per byte = 125 MB/sec.  Real world the the largest copy speed I've ever had is ~112 MB/sec per the windows popup and this is copying from a linux server (running samba-server) to a windows 7/10 pc.

You have 8 TB => 8,000,000 MB / 112 MB/s = 71,428 seconds = greater than 19 hours for a sustained transfer with zero problems.

When i do `scp` I generally see 80-90 MB/sec versus 112, thanks to the overhead of SSH.

> Why is the Linux to Linux copy so slow, and is there anything I can do to increase the speed to what I get with Windows?

My reported 112 MB/sec copy speed is downloading from linux to windows (reading) and also uploading from windows to linux (writing).  My linux servers (at work) have 512GB of RAM, and with disk caching that will mostly prevent waiting for disk to provide the data especially when writing to a system the data is delivered over the network and stored in RAM before being written to disk.  Typical real read speeds from hard disk are generally 80 MB/sec or greater so they *usually* don't have much impact especially if it's multiple in a RAID but if it's a single hard disk then that could be your bottleneck simply reading the data off it.

> I am attempting to copy files from an old NAS to *another*  one

I have experience with synology nas, on the same network and location where I see 112 MB/sec copies as explained; sometimes my NAS's will do near 100 MB/sec, may times they are doing only 50 MB/sec over a couple minutes moving a single ~10GB file.  NAS's can have various settings within them reducing network transfer speed to maintain bandwidth expecting multiple user connections to be reading/writing from it.

Your copy between 2 NAS's for 8TB of data is not a single file, so there will be some incurred overhead dealing with those millions of separate files there's no way around that unless you locally tar up chunks of data into 100+gb tar files and transfer those then do the work untarring them on the destination nas.

> Why is the Linux to Linux copy

your really not doing linux to linux, you are doing nas to nas and it is whatever *linux* operating system is on each nas and how it's configured to do networking as well as performance it can read/write to the types of storage (disks) that are in it.

Per my description of my 112 MB/sec on a 1gbps wired network, I can see that same transfer speed between linux to linux servers (not NAS); if doing `scp` then that SSH overhead is what causes the reduction to ~80MB/sec.  When you start copying thousands of small (less than 10MB) files then you can incur a lot of overhead and speed loss resulting from the operating system reading that data from its file system on whatever storage, and then again on the other system writing it all to it's storage.  *A good NAS with enough RAM can buffer the data in RAM coming over the network at which point it will be the sustained write speed it can do to it's disks, which i think those advertised numbers are often exaggerated and almost always dependent on having the max number of disks installed into the NAS, as RAID-0, so they can advertise the highest possible read/write numbers.*

as a sanity check transfer a single ~2GB file, and also a single ~30gb file, and see what those max transfer speeds are, and if they are sustained on your network.

Comment: I am currently copying a 2TB file from nas to nas (Windows had problems copying a file that large) using rsync, and seeing sustained speeds of around 18MB/sec, per `iotop`.

Answer (score 1):

Both rsync and scp encrypt the data that is sent across the wire.  On old hardware, I have found that this can limit the speed to about 20MB/s as you observe.

Try using an unencrypted copy, such as:

- running an rsync server on one end and using the rsync:// protocol
- using netcat (or nc) on both sides something like (untested, likely wrong syntax):

  - source: `tar cf - ... | nc host port`
  - destination: `nc -l port | tar xf -`